# My Google JavaScript Map will appear different depending on the browser and sometimes the computer

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API specifically the "Maps JavaScript API", and I have most of the JavaScript code done and the map is shown in my browser (Chrome).

But here is the issue, when I open the the file in Firefox browser or when I open the same file in other computers in their Chrome browser... the map will not show the right way. Mostly the issue is with the zoom feature.

On my Chrome the map will appear as following:

[image]
In firefox or some other computers the map will appear as following: 
[image]
I tried changing the code in different ways, and reading the Google documentation again. I tried using different variations of

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.panToBounds(bounds);
```

But I have not gotten any good results from it.

Here is the complete code

```
<div class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
    <style>
        #map {
            height: -webkit-fill-available;
            display: block;
            position: static !important;
        }

        body #mapOverFlow .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    </style>
    <div id="map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"></div>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var userCoor = [
                ["<div><h1>JLSKYLL REDES</h1><div><p></p><p><b>22246338</b></p></div></div>", 9.381300800000002, -
                    84.14509079999999
                ],
                ["<div><h1>Lirio Lodge</h1><div><p>Lirio Lodge is the ideal place for lovers of nature, has a privileged location in front of the beautiful Laguna Madre of God, in the channels of Tortuguero.</p><p><b>22825003</b></p></div></div>",
                    9.94591, -84.11847569999999
                ]
            ];

            var mapOptions = {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoom: 2
            };
            var marker, i, userCoordinate, map;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            var userCoorPath = [new google.maps.LatLng(9.381300800000002, -84.14509079999999), new google.maps.LatLng(
                9.94591, -84.11847569999999)];

            userCoordinate = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: userCoorPath,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });

            userCoordinate.setMap(map);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            for (i = 0; i < userCoor.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(userCoor[i][1], userCoor[i][2]),
                    map: map
                });

                var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng());
                bounds.extend(loc);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                    return function () {
                        infowindow.setContent(userCoor[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }

            center = bounds.getCenter();
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.panToBounds(bounds);
        }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initialize">
    </script>
</div>
```

The map should be shown in your browser when you open the file and add the API_KEY. Now it may appear with the zoom, or i can appear all far away.

Try in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please edit your question and embed your screenshots as images directly using the image icon above the text area instead of linking to Google drive with private access

Comment: Also, the links you've provided are behind Google's authentication. Are you really going to give view access to us all?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].  Pay close attention to the minimum requirement.  The time you spend in making it the minimum may actually help you to identify the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map has no `center` set. Note that this is a required parameter, but you never assign the value of `center = bounds.getCenter()` to your map instance. Try adding the code below:

```
const center = bounds.getCenter();
map.setCenter(center);
```

In addition, your map has a zoom level of 2. Change it to e.g. 8 if you don't want your map to appear all far away.

```
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 8
};
```

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufkxr381/1/) for demonstration and guidance. It works regardless of browser.

Hope this helps you.